# HBase shell "OutOfOrderScannerNextException" error on scanner & count calls

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nosql

Either I run a scan command or a count, this error pops up and the error message doesn't make sense to me. 
What does it say & how to solve it?

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OutOfOrderScannerNextException:
>   Expected nextCallSeq: 1 But the nextCallSeq got from client: 0;
>   request=scanner_id: 788 number_of_rows: 100 close_scanner: false
>   next_call_seq: 0

Commands:

count 'table', 5000
scan 'table', {COLUMN => ['cf:cq'], FILTER => "ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:somevalue')"}

**EDIT:**

I have added the following settings in hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>1200000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
    <value>100</value>
 </property>
```

NO IMPACT

**EDIT2: Added sleep**

```
                Result[] results = scanner.next(100);

                for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    result = results[i];
                    try {
                        ...
                        count++;
                        ...
                        Thread.sleep(10); // ADDED SLEEP
                    } catch (Throwable exception) {
                        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());

                        System.out.println("sleeping");
                    }
                }
```

**New Error after Edit2:**

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerTimeoutException: 101761ms passed since the last invocation, timeout is currently set to 60000
...


Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 31, already closed?
    ...

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 31, already closed?
    ...

FINALLY BLOCK: 9900
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerTimeoutException: 101766ms passed since the last invocation, timeout is currently set to 60000
    ...


Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerTimeoutException: 101766ms passed since the last invocation, timeout is currently set to 60000
    ...

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 31, already closed?
    ...

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.UnknownScannerException: Name: 31, already closed?
    ...
```

Comment: Which HBase version you are using?

Comment: @Chiron hbase-0.98.6.1-hadoop1 standalone on Ubuntu

Comment: I was running another scan command and the problem persists, should i use caching ?

Comment: Seriously there's no answer to this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: By using the same client version shipped with the downloaded hbase(not maven 0.99), i was able to solve this issue.
Server version is 0.98.6.1
Contains client jars inside ./lib folder

Don't forget to attach the zookeeper library

---

OLD:

Right now I did two things, changed the table connection API (0.99)

```
                    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
                    TableName name = TableName.valueOf("TABLENAME"); 
                    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
                    Table table = conn.getTable(name);
```

Then when the error pops up, i try to recreate the connection

```
                    scanner.close();
                    conn.close();
                    conf.clear();
                    conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
                    conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
                    table = conn.getTable(name);
                    table = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf).getTable(name);
                    scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

This works but is might slow after the first error it receives. Very slow to scan through all the rows

Answer (score 3):

this sometimes occurs when you did huge deletes, you need to merge empty regions and try to  balance your regions

Answer (score 1):

Can be caused by a broken disk as well. In my case it was not so broken so that Ambari, HDFS or our monitoring services noticed it, but broken enough so that it couldn't serve one region.

After stopping the regionserver using that disk, the scan worked.

I found the regionserver by running hbase shell in debug mode:

```
hbase shell -d
```

Then some regionservers appeared in the output and one of them stood out. 
Then I ran `dmesg` on the host to find the failing disk.